# I want to know some query in sql

Tags: sql

I have two different tables.

Table A is:

```
USER_ID | ROLE_ID
a       | 1
B       | 2
c       | 1
a       | 2
```

Table B is:

```
USER_ID | USER_NAME | USER_EMAIL
A       | Ankit     | abc@.com
a       | amana     | xyz@.com
c       | abc       | bcf@.com
```

Now my question is: I want to get the data of Table B if the USER_ID's have multiple entries in Table A.

Comment: Give it a try first and show us what you're stuck on and what you don't understand about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that would work in MySQL. Note that in TSQL it would be a bit different.

```
SELECT
    B.USER_ID
   ,B.USER_NAME
   ,B.USER_EMAIL
FROM
   Table_A as A
INNER JOIN
   Table_B as B
      ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
GROUP BY B.USER_ID
HAVING COUNT(B.USER_ID) > 1
```

Comment: Can confirm that T-SQL is no different.

Comment: Actually T-SQL might require grouping under the SELECT statement (ie. MIN(B.USER_ID) for it to work

Comment: no this query is not working it is giving the error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression 
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression" 
*Cause:    
*Action: 
Error at Line: 1 Column: 18

Comment: can you please help me with this @PhilK

Comment: Try grouping what's under the SELECT statement. For example: 
    `min(B.USER_ID)
   ,min(B.USER_NAME)
   ,min(B.USER_EMAIL)`

Comment: Yes it solve my problem thankyou so much